# Get date of last update and future update estimate of a package

Tags: r

I'm building a package that depends on another package's data. The dependent package has not been updated since 2012, which causes me some concern.  It's historical baseball data, so the last recorded observation should be in October, 2013. According to

```
> ps <-packageStatus()$inst
> ps[grep("Lahman", rownames(ps)),c(1, 3, 16, 17)]
#        Package Version Built Status
# Lahman  Lahman   2.0-3 3.1.0     ok
```

there are no updates available.

Is there a way to find out, preferably with R commands, the date of last update for a package and (possibly) if there is an updated version of the package coming any time soon?

Comment: Figuring out next release date will be (1) highly package specific (most packages will give no info about this; while others might allude to it on project pages on R-forge or GitHub); or (2) be highly assumption-dependent about the rate at which releases are made (e.g. by inferring a linear trend over previous release dates retrieved from the CRAN archives).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
packageDescription("Lahman")$Date
```

Gives you the last update date.  For the rest you'll have to go to the **[project page](http://lahman.r-forge.r-project.org/)**.  I don't think you can expect a function that will tell you either next release date, or what data will be included in the newest release.  As far as I know this is not a standard field.

Also, there is no reason to expect the data set should be up to date to the release date as the purpose of the package is to provide a large data set for statistic demonstrations rather than an up-to-date baseball stats repository for fantasy/scouting.